# inline if inside List removeIf

Tags: java, list, hibernate, arraylist, lambda

I have a `List`, which is the result of a `Criteria.list()`. This `Criteria` retrieves data from different tables, depending on the data type I select.

I have three entities, that are linked to tables through Hibernate:

`File.java`

```
// fields
// getters and setters
```

`Refund.java`

```
// fields
private RefundState refundState;
// getters and setters
```

`Quotation.java`

```
// fields
private QuotationState quotationState;
// getters and setters
```

`Refund` and `Quotation` classes extend File. So, Refund and Quotation have some fields in common, that in case I want to get all Files, independently by the type, I can.

But this creates a big problem. When I retrieve all Files (both Refunds and Quotations), I need to exclude Quotations and Refunds with specific States. States are different between Quotations and Refunds, so I can't apply a `Where condition` in the `Criteria`.

So, I think I have to manually remove elements from the List of results. And I can, by doing `list.removeIf(Predicate)`.

But, as the List is mixed of types, I can't just `cast`, like so:

```
list.removeIf(elem -> (((Refund) elem).getRefundState().getCode().equals("A")));
```

..because, it breaks when `elem` is a Quotation.
So, I thought of inlining an if, like so:

```
list.removeIf(elem -> (elem instanceof Refund ? ((Refund) elem).getRefundState().getCode().equals("A")));
```

But it does not even compile. It says a bracket is missing.

I **should** avoid using a `forEach` since the ResultSet can be very big.
I **can't** change any classes.
I **should** avoid making two different `Criteria`s and merging the two lists. I apply other `Where conditions` that I am not able to retrieve within the class I am executing this `removeIf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a ternary expression without the `false` part. If you add  `: false` to your filter it should compile. However, anytime you have code in the format `A ? B : false`, replace it with `A && B`. In this case:

```
elem -> elem instanceof Refund && ((Refund) elem).getRefundState().getCode().equals("A")
```

If your Java is recent enough, you can even move the cast into the `instanceof`:

```
elem -> elem instanceof Refund r && r.getRefundState().getCode().equals("A")
```

Comment: will check asap if it works. it compiles, so this deserves an upvote. I didn't know the false expression was mandatory..

Comment: it keeps deleting every entry from the list.. i clearly messed up brackets. thank you anyway